# When compiling in ConTeXt, context vs texexec

Tags: compiling, context

I'm interested in learning ConTeXt. In the past I've mainly used LyX, and a bit of LaTeX recently. I was reading [Berend de Boer's introduction to ConTeXt](http://www.berenddeboer.net/tex/LaTeX2ConTeXt.pdf), and pretty much the first thing he said about compiling was to use `texexec` instead of `context`. Why is this? What are the differences, the pros and cons of each? Or is one a subset/superset of the other?

Cheers

Comment: The document is from 2003. While command names can still be valid, I would advice you to ignore all "technical" descriptions. Context has over the years changed the scripting languages it uses. Today one should use context: http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Mark_IV.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The document is from 2003. While command names can still be valid, I would advice you to ignore all "technical" descriptions. ConTeXt has over the years changed the scripting languages it uses. Today one should use `context`: http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Mark_IV.