# What's the right way to run "context"?

Tags: context

Someone [previously](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49101/when-compiling-in-context-context-vs-texexec) asked the difference between `context` and `texexec`. [This page](https://www.contextgarden.net/MkIV_Differences) says that you "start Mark IV with the `context` command, and Mark II with `texexec`". So, I started using `context`.

But it seems that you have to run `context` multiple times in order to properly typeset a document? This is similar to LaTeX, but I don't have to think about it because I can use `latexmk`.

Is there a similar thing for ConTeXt? Or am I supposed to just run it a bunch of times each time I want to typeset something?

Comment: normally context manage the multiple compilations itself. If you look at the terminal output you will see that it often runs more than one compilation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both `context` and `texexec` are not executables (like `pdflatex`) but scripts.  Since `texexec` (which is a Ruby script) is deprecated, you can immediately forget about it and I will focus on `context`.

The contents of `context` on a Linux system are

```shell
#!/bin/sh
mtxrun --script context "$@"
```

It simply starts `mtxrun` which is a Lua script with about 26000 lines.  This script is the heart of ConTeXt and performs tasks like format generation, font database management, file lookup, etc.

The parameter `--script` specifies yet another script to run.  All available scripts can be found in the [`texmf-context/scripts/context/lua`](https://github.com/contextgarden/context-mirror/tree/beta/scripts/context/lua) folder of the Standalone distribution.  The parameter `--script context` loads the [`mtx-context.lua`](https://github.com/contextgarden/context-mirror/blob/beta/scripts/context/lua/mtx-context.lua) script.  In this script you can find the [multipass loop](https://github.com/contextgarden/context-mirror/blob/744095aa4676553437db0d71c281a74557a3222f/scripts/context/lua/mtx-context.lua#L855-L901) which essentially reads

```lua
for currentrun=1,maxnofruns do

    local returncode = -- run LuaTeX

    if not returncode then
        -- you pressed Ctrl+C
        break
    elseif returncode == 0 then
        -- check multipass data
        if multipass_changed then
            -- rerun
        else
            break
        end
    else
        -- report error and exit
        break
    end

end
```

There are some more details to it, which I left out but you can look them up in the linked file.

---

Bottomlined, that is to say, that `context` automatically runs multiple passes over your document if not instructed otherwise.  You can instruct `context` to perform only a single run with

```shell
context --once file.tex
```

or performs exactly `<n>` runs (where `<n>` is a number)

```shell
context --forcedruns=<n> file.tex
```

Comment: Hi Henri. Thanks for the very detailed response, but I posted this question really in response to behaviour I was seeing (actually when I was working on another [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/461357/cannot-change-textcolor-inside-a-makeup-in-context) which you also answered -- thank you). I have main.tex which includes title.tex which had the title page content, and found that sometimes I had to run context twice in order to get the title page background color to update (I was changing this to make sure my updates were being taken).

Comment: Now I'm quite puzzled why I need to run `context` multiple times since it appears to be designed to auto multiple times as needed.

Comment: This may be connected to your editor. Check, if its `context` command doesn't use --once option.

Comment: @Roxy Hard to say without a minimal reproducible example.  I agree with Damien that it is probably an editor problem.